# Firebase Realtime Database rules check if string includes value

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is what my rules look like:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    },
    "classes": {
      "$classid": {
        ".read": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('memberOfClasses').child('val').val().matches(*$classid*) || root.child('users').child($uid).child('ownedClasses').child('val').val().matches(*$classid*)",
        ".write": "root.child('users').child(auth.uid).child('memberOfClasses').child('val').val().matches(*$classid*) || root.child('users').child($uid).child('ownedClasses').child('val').val().matches(*$classid*)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm getting Simulation failed - Line 11: syntax error (line 11 is the classes/$classid.read). I'm guessing it has something to do with the regex in .matches(*$classid*)

I'm trying to get it so that if for example users/auth.uid/memberOfClasses or ownedClasses equals something like "154 321 ABC", I would be able to access classes/154, classes/321, and classes/ABC.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The value that you pass in to `matches` must be a string literal.

This might work: `.matches("*"+$classid+"*")`